# Crinkled new leaves on healthy flowering ipomoea/ Morning Glory. virus?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, leaves, vines, morning-glory

[image]My perfectly healthy Ipomoea tree now has wrinkled new leaves coming up? Could this be a deficiency or an infestation?

Thanks in advance[image: Healthy old leaves and new crinkled leaves.]

[![New crinkled leaves][4]][4]

[![New growth.][3]][3]

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5cqi.jpg[image]

Comment: Did you  check the underside of the leaves? If not, inspect closely to see if there's anything there...

Comment: @bamboo I did, all clear...

Comment: @bamboo have added a picture of the back of a leaf. Can you see anything?

Answer (score 1):

[Ipomoea and virus](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/02571862.2013.854415)

[Ipomoea leaf with viral infection](https://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/sweetpotato/key/Sweetpotato%20Diagnotes/Media/Html/TheProblems/DiseasesViral/ViralInfectionUnspecified/VeinClearing-PNG-JOS.JPG)

This looks like a viral infection.  Not insect at all. "Sweet Potato Latent Virus".  Insects may have been the vector. There are quite a few ipomoea viruses.  Make a positive positive ID first.

Comment: any ideas on how to treat this? looked all over the net but cant find anything.

Comment: I hate to tell you that I think there is absolutely no treatment for this viral infections.  Pretty much, once infected, that virus is in that area forever.

Comment: Wait until you've got clearer ID's of the problem, okay?

Comment: found this bug this morning.

Comment: Grins, you must love Ipomoea IpomoeaGirl!  That 'bug' looks like mealy bug.  Not unusual for these kind of normal insects to be hanging around stressed for whatever reason plants.  Your plant still looks 'vigorous'.  Soon to be flowering.  I'd wait it out unless someone else comes up with more information.  Plants want to live.  They have their own type of 'immune' system that is working hard to cauterize or compartmentalize this virus.  For the mealy bug, use a Q tip dipped in a tiny bit of vaseline.  You should be able to remove those sap suckers manually.  Such pretty plants Ipomoea!